# Is there a way to add the same row multiple times with different ids into a table with postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to add the same data for a row into my table x number of times in postgresql. Is there a way of doing that without manually entering the same values x number of times? I am looking for the equivalent of the go[count] in sql for postgres...if that exists.

Comment: What is "go[count]"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the function [`generate_series()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-srf.html), e.g.:

```sql
insert into my_table
select id, 'alfa', 'beta'
from generate_series(1,4) as id;
```

Test it in [db<>fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=0e9a9a3267c2035ebd43173d5c41107a)

Comment: does this update the auto increment?

Comment: @matt - If the primary key is auto-increment, it should be omitted from the select list, see [db<>fidlle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/KnlPsRAB)

Comment: so how would you change your code without using id?

Comment: sorry, missed that. I appreciate your help. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Idea**

Produce a resultset of a given size and cross join it with the record that you want to insert `x` times. What would still be missing is the generation of proper PK values. A specific suggestion would require more details on the data model.

**Query**

The sample query below presupposes that your PK values are autogenerated.

```
CREATE TABLE test ( id SERIAL, a VARCHAR(10), b VARCHAR(10) );

INSERT INTO test (a, b)
    WITH RECURSIVE Numbers(i) AS (
           SELECT 1
        UNION ALL
           SELECT i + 1
             FROM Numbers
            WHERE i < 5 -- This is the value `x`
    )
         SELECT adhoc.*
           FROM Numbers n
     CROSS JOIN ( -- This is the single record to be inserted multiple times
                   SELECT 'value_a' a
                        , 'value_b' b
                ) adhoc
 ;
```

See it in action in [this db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=52891abc48fcffa11331e2c5db13d7b0).

**Note / Reference**

The solution is adopted from [here](https://riptutorial.com/sql/example/2539/generating-values) with minor modifications (there are a host of other solutions to generate `x` consecutive numbers with SQL hierachical / recursive queries, so the choice of reference is somewhat arbitrary).